# How to get the names of all keys in a MongoDB collection using c# mongodb driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to get the names of all keys in a MongoDB collection using c# mongodb driver.

I think I have to use from RunCommand but this not work.

please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that didn’t work

Comment: Just add it to the question, it’s easier for people to understand the context

Comment: mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "my_collection",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
}) 

 this code is not work in c# (syntax error)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

The goal is to reproduce [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tp3toviWo8l)

- First generate an array were `k` are the keys and `v` the values for the entire collection.
- `$unwind` that array to deconstruct.
- And `$group` by `null` to get all and adding to set to avoid duplicates.

So you can try comething like this code:

```cs
var keys = collection.Aggregate()
    .Project(x => new { keyValueArray = x.ToBsonDocument().ToDictionary().Select(y => new { k = y.Key, v = y.Value }) })
    .Unwind(x => x.keyValueArray)
    .Group(x => 1, g => new { allkeys = g.Select(x => x.keyValueArray.k).ToList() }).First();
```